# Word or expression for "the most important point"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Words like "crux", "essence", etc. refer to an idea that is a synopsis of a whole larger idea. But if one writes an article about some subject including many details about it, the most important point might *not* represent the whole article. **Think of a description of a trip. There might be one detail that stands out, yet it is in no way the "crux" of the article.**

So why not use "the main point"? Because it feels too verbose to be an expression. It feels like a sentence, like saying "this is the main point". Let's assume it's being used as a heading for some paragraph.

So, is there a word or expression that means "the main point" which does not indicate a summary, and yet does not sound verbose?

**EDIT**

It looks like some people see "the main point" to mean "crux" instead of looking at it more literally. So perhaps I should have used "the **most important** point" instead. Edited now.

**EDIT 2**

Enjoying the pool, even if it was the highlight of the trip, is *not* the crux of the article. But hmmmm, maybe "highlight" is the word I'm looking for.... or maybe "tl;dr", though that would be more slangy.

Comment: Have you looked up synonyms for 'crux' (which certainly _does_ mean 'the main point'? Bottom line, core, gist, nub ...

Comment: Instead of writing "this is the main point" or even "this is the crux" (only one word less) you can just start writing *about* the main idea and not belabour it. Seems like writing "This is the first paragraph" when it is obvious.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth All of those you mentioned (aside from "Bottom line") encompass the whole matter. And "bottom line" is only appropriate in specific cases. An article might be more than 50% not included in the _main_ point.

Comment: @WeatherVane What about a heading?

Comment: Just as you don't put a heading as "Paragraph One" you should not use "Main Point" but *summarise* that point in the heading. So for example "Brindles are drongish."

Comment: "[T]he main point" doesn't feel too verbose to be (an expression?) to me. And if 'main point' is semantically fine (if not in the opinion of some stylistically so), the close synonym 'crux' must also be semantically fine.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edited now. I hope the crux of my question is clearer now. :)

Comment: @ispiro The word [**crux**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crux) is *still* the answer as far as I'm concerned: "**2** : an essential point requiring resolution or resolving an outcome; **3** : a main or central feature (as of an argument)." Isn't that the definition of what you want?

Comment: @JasonBassford 3 - No. That's why it mentions "(as of an argument)" - to tell us that it's a part of one big issue, not loosely related parts. As for 2 - if you concentrate on the "essential" - as above. And if you concentrate on "an...point" (meaning optionally one of many) then yes. But it's just not used that way (and I doubt that's really what they meant).

Comment: @ispiro *As of* is just a simile or analogy. *Crux* is used in that sense in many other contexts, none of them having to do with arguments. But I'm still failing to understand what you're saying. There are many separate issues. The crux of them all is one of the issues. However, they must surely be related in some way to a whole. The most important point, the pivotal point, the crucial point, the crux of the matter. They all mean essentially the same thing, and *crux* is the shortest way of expression it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes. I understand that. My point was that "(as of an argument)" is to point out that the crux is part of one big issue. I didn't mean (or say) that it's necessarily part of an _argument_.

Comment: @ispiro I'm going to stop commenting now. I remain unable to understand the problem with *crux* that would make you look for something else, or, given that, what that something else could be. Maybe somebody else can figure it out …

Comment: @JasonBassford  Enjoying the pool, even if it was the highlight of the trip, is _not_ the crux of the article. But hmmmm, maybe highlight is the word I'm looking for....

Comment: Do you mean “the most interesting thing to you” even if it was not the author’s main point.  E.g.:  “Even though the main point of the article was how to take a logarithm, what I found most interesting was how he always said, “We” instead of “you”  when explaining things.”

Comment: 'Highlight' certainly seems to fit with the trip example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **takeaway**? From M-W:

> **[takeaway](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/takeaway)**: a conclusion to be made based on presented facts or information : a main point or key message to be learned or understood from something experienced or observed

Re your question, "So, is there a word or expression that means "the main point" which does not indicate a summary, and yet does not sound verbose?": **Takeaway** conveys the meaning of "the main point" without indicating a summary and without sounding as verbose as "the main point.".